# What is Visio and what are its uses?

Tags: microsoft-visio

While browsing I came across this application MS Visio. So want to know what does it do and how does it help. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Did you even *try* finding out for yourself?

Comment: +1 for skaffman.  When the question itself is so short and vague, I won't bother writing an answer.

Comment: +1 skaffman Time to help yourself on this one @Kalven

Answer (score 1):

Visio is a Microsoft tool for drawing diagrams, including database diagrams.

When it comes to database stuff, it supports reverse engineering, so you start from an existing database and automatically obtain you db diagram.

Depending on your needs, there are a lot of Visio alternatives. For simpler diagrams you can check out some on line applications too.